# SSL and PLAINTEXT in Kafka

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

Can we use PLAINTEXT and SSL in the Production environment, especially when brokers are within the same sub net and they are protected by Firewall? 
I want to use SSL only for external connections like Kafka Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can list as many listeners as you have ports available in the `listeners` property on the brokers.

For instance, you can define `PLAINTEXT_SASL` between the brokers for replication, and allow for `PLAINTEXT`/`PLAINTEXT_SASL` & `SSL`/`SASL_SSL` for external traffic

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it makes sense to have such kind of combination.